# SNMP trap on Windows service stop

Tags: windows, snmp, windows-update

I'm trying to send traps when a Windows service e.g. Windows Update is stopped.

In evntwin I tried adding all events with Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient origin but stopping/restarting the service I don't receive any traps, even if I send a test trap from MIB Browser it works.

How can I find the correct event and what can I do to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The events you are looking for are from the source "Service Control Manager". Look for events like 7036(start/stop) and filter your service from the contents (aka 'the message').

It's no possible to send one special Trap just in one special case, without triggering it manually. If you want to do this without manual triggerst, you will have to parse the events content before Evntwin'ning them or filter the events on the destination side.